# Merging a new rxjs observable into existing subscribed observable

Tags: rxjs

I have an rxjs observable which is already subscribed to:

```js
const o = new rxjs.Subject();
o.subscribe( (v) => console.log("value: " + v);
```

Due to some unrelated event, e.g. a user clicking on a button, I need to go and fetch data from the server, and put that data into the existing observable `o`. Using axios, I have something like this:

```js
const aPromise = axios.get("someurl...")
```

I then do the following:

```js
const secondObservable = rxjs.of(aPromise)
                             .subscribe( (response) => o.next(response.data) )
```

My question is whether there is a better way to put the response data into the existing already subscribed to observable, perhaps using operators?

Comment: Perhaps `axios.get(...).then(response => o.next(response.data)).catch(error => o.error(error);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you need data from your original stream and might get updates from a button click — then we'll need to create a stream of button clicks, e.g.

```ts
const btnClick$ = new rxjs.Subject();

onClick(){
  this.btnClick$.next(void 0);
}
```

Then we'll turn this `btnClick$` stream into a http-get request stream, using [`switchMap`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/switchMap/):

```js
const request$ = btnClick$.pipe(
  // each click will be turned into a http-get
  switchMap(() => rxjs.of(axios.get("someurl...")))
)
```

And we're ready to consume results from both streams, original and a stream of possible data updates from server on button click:

```js
// we'll take results both from original stream
// and our new possible source of data
merge(original$, request$).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Heres a little app using mocks:

```js
const { fromEvent, of, merge } = rxjs;
const { map, delay, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

// create a stream of btn clicks
const theButton = document.getElementById('the-btn');
const btnClicks$ = fromEvent(theButton, 'click');

console.log('Processing...');

// clicks turned into http-gets
const request$ = btnClicks$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => makeRequest())
);

// original source of data
const original$ = of('Please, click the button!').pipe(delay(500));

merge(original$, request$)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });

// mock for requests
function makeRequest(){
  return of(Date.now()).pipe(delay(500))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button
  id="the-btn"
  >Click me!</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is more convoluted that OP's original solution they were looking to simplify.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, I guess I assumed that `Subject` was given just as an example and in real code OP has `Observable`. Also, imho, approach with `merge` has better separation of concerns. While I agree that approach suggested by you and Richard Matsen looks simpler.

Comment: whilst complexer, I like the use of `merge` and `switchMap`. Am I right in thinking that `switchMap` is used to "convert" the new observable/promise into a value, because just using `map` wouldn't changeit from an observable/promise into a value?

Comment: @AntKutschera, yep you're right. `switchMap` is needed to substitute a value with a stream of values (a click event with a http-get request stream, in our case). Please, also note that there are similar operators, like [`mergeMap`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/mergeMap/), [`concatMap`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/concatMap/) and [`exhaustMap`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/exhaustMap/), check [this comparison](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/ba116f84fe9f1493b989902c0927bb35) to pick the right one for your needs. GL

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the result of the call directly to your observable.

```js
const axios = {
  get: url => Promise.resolve('some value')
};

const o = new rxjs.Subject();
o.subscribe(v => { console.log("value: " + v); });

axios.get('url').then(data => { o.next(data); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think, with this approach it would be cool to do `from(axios.get('url')).subscribe(o)`. **UPD** uhh, but it will complete the Subject, damn. Ignore this, sorry. Yet, you'll need some error pushing as well. And it'd be cool to do via `.subscribe(o)`... :)

Comment: I did try that initially.

Comment: I meant to say that you'll need to add an error propagation as well, e.g. `.then(o.next.bind(o), o.error.bind(o))`.

Comment: This solution doesn't wrap the axios promise in an observable, but still calls `next` on the first observable. I'm OK with that, if it's standard and accepted by the community, but I wondered if there was a more accepted way of doing it without calls to `next`.

Comment: No need to wrap a promise just to unwrap it.